# Update android studio : preview add a lot of shadow

Tags: android-studio, updates, shadow

since the last update, I have a shadow on every of my element in preview layout (with the XML)

How do I remove them ?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post screenshot of the preview window.

Comment: See my updated post

Comment: I think it's the bug with new version of Android Studio. I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54196318/5180017) which is similar to your problem and was asked after your question. I'd suggest you to raise the bug report.

Comment: ok thank you I will

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio disable shadow around textview in layout editor in version 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211300/android-studio-disable-shadow-around-textview-in-layout-editor-in-version-3-3)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move your cursor into a preview layout and then move cursor out of a layout, shadows should disapear..
[image]