# Android Studio 3.3 xml preview internal shadows on LinearLayout

Tags: android-studio

I just updated Android Studio to the version 3.3

Now, in every XML file, each nested LinearLayout has an internal shadow on the left and right side. 
How it can be removed?

[image]

Comment: I think you're not only the one who is getting this [weird shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54195573/5180017)

Comment: Hope you find solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211447/1318946

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio disable shadow around textview in layout editor in version 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211300/android-studio-disable-shadow-around-textview-in-layout-editor-in-version-3-3)