# Android studio disable shadow around textview in layout editor in version 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

There is a weird shadow at the left and right of `TextView` when it is wrapped with in `LinearLayout` in android studio 3.3 . This shadow does not appear in device after installation , it only appears in editor . Is this a bug or new feature for some indication in android studio ?  If this is a feature , Is there a way to disable it ?

[image]

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Shadow Appear"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Removing `LinearLayout` removes that shadow. It is also showing a warning 

`This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless.

Inspection info:A layout with children that has no siblings, is not a scrollview or a root layout, and does not have a background, can be removed and have its children moved directly into the parent for a flatter and more efficient layout hierarchy.`

Comment: @kvaruna That layout was only for test purpose, It appears in real layouts too when there are no useless parents

Comment: Then this might me an improvement in update to show width of `textview`.

Comment: it might relates to fading, have you tried to set isHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled = false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shadow is **just to highlight LinearLayout orientation** while in preview and not when the app is installed.

`LinearLayout` has two options for orientation: `horizontal` & `vertical`. By default, if not declared, the orientation is considered as `horizontal`, thus showing the shadow at both the vertical ends. Similarly, when we declare orientation as `vertical`, it shows shadows at both the horizontal ends.

I haven't found a way to disable it till now. Probably AS 3.3 does not provide it. I'll still try to find and see if I can disable shadows .

Comment: shadow does not appear if it is not wrapped with in linear layout , that make it look like bug to me not sure though .

Comment: Sorry I removed all opinion part in which you put some effort . It is not required and is hiding main answer .

Comment: Android Studio 3.4 Beta 2 does not have this issue and works as expected. I've started using this version as my main version, because AS 3.3 is completely useless because of this issue. The entire Preview Editor is useless.