# How to disable shadows in LinearLayout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an activity which has a `constraintLayout` at the top and a `FrameLayout` that wraps a `LinearLayout` in itself.

How exactly can I disable the shadows that the `LinearLayout` has at the top and bottom of itself, for a better user experience?

I tried setting `android:elevation="0dp"` inside my `LinearLayout`, but nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

Current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/golden_brown"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_profile"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_navbar_fade"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@null"
        app:itemRippleColor="@null"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/icon_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/icon_color_selector"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyleActive"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyleInactive"
        app:itemIconSize="40dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, a simple LinearLayout should not have shadows. 
Please check whether the shadow actually appears in the emulator or a real device, and not only in the XML Editor in Android Studio. The XML Editor sometimes shows shadows around the element that the cursor currently stands above. 
There also is a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211447/8331157) that suggests the shadow appears to indicate which `orientation` is set to the LinearLayout.

Comment: How would I then set the background color of my LinearLayout?

Comment: The FrameLayout surrounding your LinearLayout has a white background anyway. So if you set your LinearLayout background to transparent, it should be white.
Are you displaying any content inside of the LinearLayout?

Comment: And also, can you reproduce the shadow on the Emulator or a physical device?

Comment: Thanks, I actually couldn't test it out as I hadn't had my phone when I asked the question, but now I can clearly see that there are no shadows. Why are they in Android Studio though? Just for orientation?

Comment: It seems not totally clear why it is there. This answer suggests that it is meant to indicate the `orientation` of the LinearLayout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211447/8331157
I'll edit my answer to point that out more clearly.